# Android studio - Bluetooth application for broadcast and receiving data

Tags: android, bluetooth, esp32

I am currently working on a project where I need to create an application for Android which will show data from a vehicle and also will be able to broadcast commands to CAN bus. I got the thing working if I only use one activity/screen, but when I started to register more data I decided to open new activity where I would only show data recived and on the first screen I would broadcast commands. Problem is I am having all my bluetooth inicialization in MainActivity, I googled a bit and it seems I need bluetooth service and then I will be able to call .write from MainActivity and .read from second if I got that right?

It's my first project so I don't understand all that activity, service thing...
Thanks for all help.

Comment: The foreground service is only needed when you want the app to communicate with BLE device in the background.

Comment: Hi thanks for reaching out. Do you have any idea how else to fix this thing then?